# Empty Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I created Pivot charts for a given data. Next I added more rows to my data by -> Pivot Chart Analyze -> Change Data Source In Pivot table there are data (rows - months, columns - value of some measure), but the plot is empty (both x and y axis looks good). What is the reason and what can I do?

Comment: What does the data look like before and after the update to the dataset?

Comment: You should add some screenshots of your query, so that it makes easier for community members to provide some assistance !